# How to implement simple notifications in drf + react?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

Normally in django with templates I implement basic notifications like this.

For example.

```
class Article(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
   
class Comment():
   article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
   txt = models.CharField()
   user = models.ForeginKey()
   datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  
class ArticleNotification():
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    msg = models.CharField()
    is_seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

If someone commented on article the owner will see notifications.

```
   @transaction.atomic
   def post_comment(request, article_id):
      comment = Comment.objects.create(article_id=article_id, txt="Nice Article", user=request.user)
      ArticleNotification.objects.create(article_id=article_id, msg=f"User {request.user} commented on your post")
```

Now to show the notifications I normally make a context processor:

```
# context_processor:
def notifcations(request):
    notifs = Notfication.objects.filter(article__owner=request.user).order_by("-datetime")
    return {"notifs":notifs}
```

In this way I can normally implement basic notification system with refresh.

Now in (drf + react) what will be the preferred way for this type of task.
Instead of context processor should I have to make an get api to list notifications
And call this api on every request from react frontend  ?

Comment: You should add some details. How often do you need to update the list of notifications? How many users at most would use the app simultaneously? Do you need to update notifications immediately after some events at front-end app? You you didn't implement any pagination logic here, why?

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak i need to show the notifications on the frontend immediately(2-3 mins late would be no problem)  after some notification objects has been created in the backend.

Comment: What about the other questions? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead of context processor should I have to make an get api to list notifications

Yes. You can create DRF API view like this

`serializers.py`

```
class ArticleNotificationSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ArticleNotification
        fields = ["id", "article", "msg", "is_seen", "datetime"]
```

`views.py`

```
class ArticleNotificationListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ArticleNotificationSerializer
    queryset = ArticleNotification.objects.all()
```

`urls.py`

```
path('notification', ArticleNotificationListView.as_view()),
```

> And call this api on every request from react frontend ?

Yes. Also you can check for Notifications for every 10 seconds with [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) and [componentDidMount hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) in your react component.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    this.countdown = setInterval(function() {
        axios.get(
           '/notifications/'
        ).then(r => 
            this.setState({ notifications: r.data }); // Changing state
        )
    }, 10000);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

For real-time notification, you need something like Django channels or you can set a get api from react which runs after every defined time (say 5 minutes) and would fetch the required notifications based on user.

In your case things in context processor would be in listapiview and later you can fetch all the list.